How to add more than one pdf page element using Flutter
I would like to add several elements to a pdf page using Flutter's pdf package.
The issue is that I can only add one element using the code below.
I need to add a heading to appear in the top center of the page.
Then, I need to add a table with at least 2 columns and multiple rows.
Each column will have its own list of elements.
At the bottom, I need to add a page number in the Footer.
Could you please provide your feedback.
Thank You
my code:
pdf.addPage(pw.Page(pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.standard,build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Table(border: pw.TableBorder.all(), children: [
            pw.TableRow(children: [
              pw.Container(child: pw.Text('Name')),
            ])]);
        }));


Try these:
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

void generatePdf() async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Column(
          children: [
            //title
            pw.Center(
              child: pw.Text(
                'top title',
                style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight:pw.FontWeight.bold),
              ),
           ),
            pw.SizedBox(height: 20), // Space between title and table

            // table
            pw.Table(
              border: pw.TableBorder.all(),
              children: [
                pw.TableRow(
                  children: [
                    pw.Padding(
                      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: pw.Text('Column 1 - Row 1'),
                    ),
                     pw.Padding(
                      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: pw.Text('Column 2 - Row 1'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                pw.TableRow(
                  children: [
                    pw.Padding(
                      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: pw.Text('Column 1 - Row 2'),
                    ),
                    pw.Padding(
                      padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: pw.Text('Column 2 - Row 2'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            pw.Spacer(), // Dynamic spacing to move content up

            // Page number in the footer
            pw.Align(
              alignment: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
              child: pw.Text(
                'Page 1',
                style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: PdfColors.grey),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  // Save the PDF file
  final output = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final file = File('${output.path}/example.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
}

